# How long does cloaking take to recharge?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I know that level one cloaking last 5 seconds, level 2 cloaking lasts 10 seconds, level 3 cloaking last 15 seconds. But how long does it take to recharge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [wiki page](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Cloaking) (and as Skeptical Chymist mentioned), a cloaking device requires 4 lapses of ion damage recovery to recharge.

This [other wiki page](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/Weapons#Ion) says that "for each ion damage a weapon causes, the cooldown increases by **five seconds**"; a cloaking device would therefore take 20 seconds to recharge.

Answer (score 4):

It requires 4 lapses of ion damage recovery - basically, at the cloak icon, after cloaking, it will display a little countdown thing. This starts at 4 and counts down to 0. Note that it isn't really disabled by ion damage after you use it, or it doesn't have to - it just represents that the use of the machine has been temporarily disabled.

Comment: Is that 4 seconds? It seems longer...

Comment: @ColonelPanic No, it's four rotations on the little circle that appears over the cloak icon in the bottom-left of your screen.